# How to download mp3 files from a website using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, download-manager

Goal: I have a list of links that link to a mp3 file which I would like to save to a directory.

Example: This is an example of a link that I stored in a list of python
http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=ydcYNJkoDxZhuV7x4neb4zcTaVJmCX9q&e=54

I tried using the requests module like so, however, this has not worked to save a file.

```
with open('static/'+url[url.rfind('/')+1:],'wb') as saved_file:
response = requests.get(mp3_url, stream=True)
if not response.ok:
    print("[-] Response did not return OK.")
for block in response.iter_content(1024):
    if not block:
        break
    saved_file.write(block)
```

Comment: define 'has not worked' ? and fix the indentation of the code. Important here.

Comment: If the link you provided is what your 'mp3_url' is, this will not work. The url is to the page which has the download link, not the mp3 url itself. You need 'mp3_url' to be of the url of the actual mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use selenium.

Then, for each youtube title you want to download you would:

- construct a url of the form http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtube code here
- open a page with this url
- find and click on the 'Download MP3' button in that page.